# mypy daemon keeps crashing

Tags: python, vscode-extensions, daemon, mypy

I have been using mypy and the mypy vs code extension for a while but recently I started to have an issue with the mypy daemon.

Below the traceback of the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypy\dmypy_server.py", line 230, in serve
  File "mypy\dmypy_server.py", line 273, in run_command
  File "mypy\dmypy_server.py", line 332, in cmd_run
  File "mypy\dmypy_server.py", line 389, in check
  File "mypy\dmypy_server.py", line 424, in initialize_fine_grained
  File "mypy\build.py", line 180, in build
  File "mypy\build.py", line 256, in _build
  File "mypy\build.py", line 2680, in dispatch
  File "mypy\build.py", line 2838, in load_graph
  File "mypy\build.py", line 1909, in __init__
  File "mypy\build.py", line 2070, in parse_file
  File "mypy\build.py", line 798, in parse_file
  File "mypy\parse.py", line 25, in parse
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 196, in parse
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 370, in visit
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 731, in visit_Module
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 409, in translate_stmt_list
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 370, in visit
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 744, in visit_FunctionDef
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 842, in do_func_def
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 481, in as_required_block
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 409, in translate_stmt_list
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 370, in visit
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 1020, in visit_AnnAssign
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 1645, in visit
  File "mypy\fastparse.py", line 1882, in visit_Subscript
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'col_offset'
```

I tried with various combinations of mypy and vs code extension versions:

- mypy (from 0.960 to 0.971)
- mypy VSCode Extension (from 0.2.0 to 0.2.1)

Did anybody face a similar situation ?